# Emploi du pronom neutre 'le'

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe, prénoms

Je ne comprends l'emploi dudit **le** impersonnel. Ex.

> **Ce que** vous avez cru facile ne **l'** est pas. (Balzac)

Pourquoi 'le' s'emploie-t-il dans cette phrase ?

> Cette dissertation est plus facile **que** je ne **l'** aurais cru.

Idem.

> Tu ne les avais pas, je **le** sais.

Pourquoi `je le sais` et pas `je sais` ?

> À cette époque j'en étais le propriétaire. Je ne **le** suis plus.

Peut-on ignorer **le** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans les premier et quatrième exemples, le pronom est indispensable car *avoir* et *être* sont transitifs et exigent (à peu près toujours) un complément d'objet mais dans la deuxième et la quatrième, *savoir* et *croire* peuvent être employés intransitivement et le pronom est donc optionnel (et c'est la forme la plus courante en français parlé) :

> Cette dissertation est plus facile que je n'aurais cru.
>
> Tu ne les avais pas, je sais.

Answer (score 2):

Dans la majorité des cas, on ne peut pas l'ignorer.  Dans la première phrase, la raison est simple: enlever le pronom impersonnel ne laisserait rien en tant que complément pour le verbe "être":

> Ce (...) n'est pas ____.

Bien que le mot "facile" a été employé dans la première proposition, ce n'est pas une partie de la deuxième proposition, alors on a besoin du pronom impersonnel pour servir de complément pour le verbe.

Dans le deuxième exemple, en voit une construction similaire: le verbe "croire" a besoin d'un complément d'objet si on fait référence à croire quelque chose en particulier.

Le troisième exemple est identique: Je sais quoi ?  On y répond avec mot "le", qui agit comme complément d'objet et comme lien avec la proposition précédente.

Le quatrième est lui-aussi identique: dire que je ne suis plus sans complément voudrait dire que je n'existe plus, n'ayant que le lien d'être dans la même phrase que la première proposition à cette dernière.

Alors, **non,** on ne doit pas ignorer le pronom *le,* il est nécessaire pour compléter la proposition et pour lier avec ce qui vient avant.