# La porte n'est pas encore ouverte, elle ne le / la sera qu'à 10 heures ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Pourriez-vous me dire laquelle de ces phrases est correcte :

> La porte n'est pas encore ouverte, elle ne *le* sera qu'à 10 heures.

ou

> La porte n'est pas encore ouverte, elle ne *la* sera qu'à 10 heures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La première est correcte. « Le » a pour antécédent « être ouverte » ((TLFi) « le » peut renvoyer aussi à un contenu propositionnel mentionné auparavant dans le discours ou qui va l'être par la suite (sous forme d'une assertion, d'un ordre, d'une question)) ; cet antécédent ou référent ne peut être ni masculin ni féminin, ni pluriel (voir NB) il est neutre.

NB : Ni pluriel, non plus.

> Ex. Les portes ne sont pas encore ouvertes, elles ne le seront qu'à dix heures.

Comment: Ni pluriel, non plus : *Les portes ne sont pas encore ouvertes, elles ne **le** seront qu'à dix heures.*

Answer (score 3):

> La porte n'est pas encore ouverte, elle ne le sera qu'à 10 heures.

En complément à l'autre excellente réponse, je signale des exemples instructifs de l'usage du *le impersonnel (pronom neutre le)* :

> Ce que vous avez cru facile ne l'est pas. (Balzac)
>
> Cette dissertation est plus facile que je ne l'aurais cru.
>
> Tu ne les avais pas, je le sais.
>
> À cette époque j'en étais le propriétaire. Je ne le suis plus.

Voir aussi la question :

[Emploi dudit "le" impersonal (prénom neutre le)](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29493/emploi-dudit-le-impersonal-pr%C3%A9nom-neutre-le)

Pour plus de détails, consulter l'article :

http://uoh.concordia.ca/pronoms/co/m/co/Le_pronom_neutre_le_-_B1.html